# How can I get one line only from river network extraction GRASS?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, extract

I have used the grass function r.watershed to get the river network by calculating the accumulation. However, as an output when I want to extract the river network by applying a filter on the accumulation (Number of cells that drain through each cell) I get a raster and then when I extract it in a shapefile I get both right side and left side of the river network. My goal is to extract only the middle line of the river network. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

The typical use of `r.watershed` would include an output raster of streams (and another raster of basins) based on the user's chosen threshold value. Then that stream raster is converted to a line vector using two simple commands:

```
r.thin input=streams output=streams_thin
r.to.vect input=streams_thin output=streams type=line
```

The streams raster is derived from flow accumulation, but there's no need for any filter. Just enter the required threshold value.

HTH